# Given two indep standard normal RVs, X and Y, what is $P(X^2 + Y^2 \leq 1)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Given two standard normal random RVs, X and Y, how do you find $P(X^2 + Y^2 \leq 1)$?

I approached this by integrating the bivariate using polar coordinates as $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Not sure if this is correct way or if there's a better way.

My approach:

$$
P(X^2 + Y^2 \leq 1) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^1 \exp(-\frac{1}{2}) dr d\theta \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}) d\theta \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi \exp(-\frac{1}{2}) \\
= \exp(-\frac{1}{2})
$$

Comment: Why are you taking $x^2+y^2=1$ for the entire integration region? That holds only on the boundary of the unit disk. The correct integral would be $\dfrac 1{2\pi}\exp(-r^2/2)r$ where the factor of $r$ comes from the Jacobian of the transformation from the Cartesian $xy$-coordinate system to the polar $r\theta$-coordinate system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $dxdy=rdrd\theta$ we get $$P(X^{2}+Y^{2} \leq 1)$$ $$=\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int _0^{1} e^{-r^{2}/2} rdrd\theta$$ $$ ={-e^{-r^{2}/2}}|_0^{1}=1-e^{-1/2}.$$

Comment: Knew I was doing something wrong, thanks mate